# Are there concurrent designs where the actor model isn't good for?

Tags: multithreading, design-patterns, concurrency

I've noticed that all designs I have come across can be multi-threaded using the actor mode - separating each work module into a different actor and using a message queue (for me a .NET ConcurrentQueue) to pass messages. What other good multi threaded models exist?

Comment: I think the lack of attention your question is getting may be because not many people are taught this sort of thing. People learn about threading in the context of semaphores, shared memory, etc, and generally that's it. Outfits like Microsoft are doing their best to hide threads from the programmer - tasks in a thread pool, asynchronous IO with completion events, etc. CSP itself is a process calculi, and if that phrase doesn't put of the average programmer I don't know what will! The result of this poor teaching is that quite a lot of programmers find threads hard and a little bit scary.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To add to my last, there are various other multi threading models beyond CSP. This [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_calculus) lists several others like [CCS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calculus_of_Communicating_Systems), [ACP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebra_of_Communicating_Processes), and [LOTOS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Of_Temporal_Ordering_Specification). Reading those articles hints at a deep and dark cavern where academics roam, waiting to pounce on a stray software developer.

The problem is that academic obscurity often means a complete lack of tools and libraries at the practical, usable level. It takes a lot of effort to convert a sound, proven academic study into a set of libraries and tools. There's little real incentive for the wider software community to take up a theoretical paper and turn it into a practical reality.

I like CSP because it's actually dead simple to implement your own CSP library based on select() or pselect(). I've done that several times now (I must learn about code re-use), plus the nice people at Kent University put together JCSP for those who like Java. I don't recommend developing in Occam (though it's still just about possible); support and maintainability are going to be issues going forward. CSP is probably the easiest one to get into, and given its good characteristics it's well worthwhile.

Comment: Coming real soon now is a new Clojure core.async library that is based on the ideas from CSP and Occam but has the benefit (over JCSP) of not being tied to real threads.

Comment: The async part is a deviation from the intent of CSP (which is strictly synchronous), and it sounds like Clojure will resemble the Actor Model. Nothing wrong with that of course! The general shape and architecture of Actor Model and CSP systems is almost identical. However the CSP variant is mathematically analysable (because of the synchronicity), whereas the Actor Model variant isn't. Not being tied to real threads? Hmmm, Ada runtimes used to do that and I can remember the "glorious day" (so I heard) that Greenhill's Ada compiler for VxWorks started using real threads instead!

Comment: @bazza you can edit your answers you know, instead of leaving 3 answers! ;-)  All interesting stuff, thanks.

Comment: @DavidRoussel, they are getting quite long aren't they! Glad it's interesting, glad to be of service :)

Answer (score 16):

Communicating Sequential Processes is, I think, a far better model for concurrency than the actor model. It addresses a number of problems with the actor model (and other models) such as deadlock, livelock, starvation. Take a look at [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Communicating_sequential_processes) and, more practically useful, [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JCSP).

The main difference is as follows. In the actor model a message is sent asynchronously. However in CSP messages are sent synchronously; the sender cannot send until the receiver is ready to receive.

This one simple restriction makes the world of difference. If you've got an incorrect design with deadlock potential then in the actor model it may or may not occur (and it usually occurs only when demo-ing to the boss...). However in CSP the deadlock will always occur, leaving you in no doubt that your design is incorrect. Ok, so you've still got to fix it but that's OK; fixing problems you *know* are there is much easier than attempting to exhaustively test for the absence of problems (your only choice in the actor model).

The strictly synchronous approach of CSP seems like it will cause problems with response times; for example one fears that a GUI thread can't move on because it's not been able to send a message to a busy worker thread that's not got as far as its 'read'. What you have to do is to ensure that the workload is spread across enough threads so that they can all get back to waiting for new messages within an acceptable period of time. CSP doesn't let you get away with it. The actor model does, however don't be deceived; you're just building up future problems.

In .NET a ConcurrentQueue is not the right primitive for CSP, not unless you layer a synchronising mechanism on top. I've added strict synchronisation on top of TCP sockets too. In fact I generally end up writing some sort of library that abstracts both sockets and pipes so that it becomes immaterial as to whether a 'Process' (as they're known in CSP parlance) is a thread on this machine or a whole other process on another machine at the end of a network connection. Nice - scalabilty built in from the very beginning.

I've been doing it the CSP way for 23 years now, I won't do it any other way. Built some big systems with thousands of threads that way.

==EDIT==

It seems this answer is still attracting some attention, so I thought I'd add to it. For Windows developers there is the [DataFlow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228603%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) namespace for the Task Parallel Library. It has to be separately downloaded. Microsoft desribe it thusly: "This dataflow model promotes actor-based programming by providing in-process message passing for coarse-grained dataflow and pipelining tasks." Excellent! It uses classes like [BufferBlocks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh160414%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) as communications channels. The important thing is that a BufferBlock has a [BoundedCapacity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.dataflowblockoptions.boundedcapacity%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property that defaults to Unbounded, which fits the Actor model. Set this to a value of 1, and you have now transformed it into a CSP-style communcation channel.

Comment: Interesting -- would there be any benefit in testing/debugging with synchronous message-sending (to detect any deadlocks), and then afterwards disabling the synchronization for the release (e.g. to get better performance, since sending threads wouldn't have to wait?).  Also, what sort of "future problems" were you referring to in the fourth paragraph?  Memory exhaustion?

Comment: @JeremyFriesner - see separate answer

Comment: @bazza Hi, [I'm looking for a way to use CSP in F#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35493139/what-apis-to-use-for-implement-csp-goroutines-in-net-f). How use DataFlow for this?

Comment: @mamcx I'm afraid I know nothing about F#. Presumably you can just use dataflow? Also note that whilst you can get close to CSP by setting the bounded capacity to 1, for it to be true CSP it'd have to be 0.

Answer (score 7):

@JeremyFriesner

**Future Problems**

To expand on what I meant by "future problems", I was referring to the fact that in an asynchronous system the sender of messages has no knowledge as to whether the receiver is actually keeping up with the demand. The sender doesn't know because all it knows is that some message buffer has accepted the message. The transport underneath (e.g. tcp) then gets on with the job of pushing the message over as and when the receiver is willing to accept it.

Thus it might be that when under stress the system fails to perform as required, because the message transport will inevitably have a limited capacity to absorb messages that the receiver can't accept yet. The sender only finds this out *after* the problem has already begun to develop, by which time it might be too late to do anything about it.

Testing of course can reveal this problem, but you have to be careful that the testing really has exhausted the transport's ability to absorb messages. Just a quick blast at full speed might be deceiving.

Of course, a synchronous system imposes an overhead ("are you ready yet?", "no, not yet", "now?", "yes!", "here you are then") which just doesn't happen in an asynchronous system. So on average the asynchronous system will be more efficient, might actually have a higher throughput, etc. Which is why most the of the worlds systems are actually asynchronous, but also the reason why systems don't always reach the full capacity that the raw network bandwidths / processing times might suggest. When approaching full capacity asynchronous systems tend not to limit gracefully, in my opinion. Token Bus (nb *not* Token Ring) was a good example of a synchronous network with totally dependable and deterministic throughput but was just a little bit slower than Ethernet and Token Ring...

Having always been blessed with a surfeit of bandwidth in my problems I've chosen the synchronous route for certainty-of-success reasons; I'm not really losing out much on bandwidth, but I am losing tons of risk, which is good.

**Convert from Synchronous to Asynchronous**

Maybe, but it's possibly of little value. In a synchronous system it only works as per the requirement if you have successfully balanced the division of labour between threads. That is, there are enough threads doing the slow bits so that the fast bits aren't held back. Get that wrong and the system definitely isn't quick enough.

But having done that you have a system where every component is able to send messages onwards with no delay, because everything it is sending to is ready and waiting (because of your skill and judgement at balancing out the workloads). So if you did then convert to an asynchronous message transport all you're doing is saving fractionally small amounts of time in the transport of those messages. You're not making changes that will result in the workloads getting processed quicker. However, if saving bandwidth is the goal then perhaps its worthwhile.

Of course, doing this balancing can be a difficult thing, and dealing with variabilities like HDD access times, networks, etc can be difficult to overcome. I've often had to implement a 'next available' workload sharing scheme. But certainly in real time signal processing systems like the ones I play with you're basically dealing with a very dependable transport like OpenVPX's RapidIO, you're only doing sums on the data (not dealing with databases, disks, etc), and the data rates are very high (1GByte/sec is perfectly doable these days, and in fact I was handling data rates that high 13 years ago; that was haaard work). Being strictly synchronous means that you're either definitely keeping up with the data rate or definitely not. With asynchronous, it's more of a maybe...

**Real Time OS for Everyone!**

Having a real time OS is an essential component too, and these days it seems to be the PREEMPT_RT patch set for Linux that does the job for a lot of people in the trade. Redhat do a prepack spin of that (RedHat MRG), but for a freebie Scientific Linux from the nice people at CERN is good and free! I strongly suspect that a lot of systems would work much more smoothly near their capacity limits if PREEMPT_RT was used - it does a good job of smoothing things out.

Answer (score 4):

Concurrency is a fascinating topic with a lot of approaches to implementation with the fundamental question being  - **"How do I coordinate parallel computations?"**.

Some models of concurrency are:

## **Futures**

**Futures** also known as **Promises** or **Tasks** are objects that act as proxies for an asynchronously calculated result. When the value is actually needed for a calculation the thread freezes until the calculation is complete and thus, synchronization is achieved.

Futures are the preferred concurrency model for **.NET** and **ES6**.

## **Software Transactional Memory**

**Software Transactional Memory (STM)** synchronizes access to shared memory (much like locks) by grouping actions into transactions. Any single transaction only sees a single view of the shared memory and is atomic. This is conceptually similar to how many databases deal with concurrency.

STM is the preferred concurrency model for **Clojure** and **Haskell**.

## **The Actor Model**

**The Actor Model** focuses of message passing. An actor receives a message and can decide to send a message in response, spawn other actors, make local changes etc. This is, probably, the least tightly coupled model of these discussed as Actors exchange messages only and nothing else.

The Actor Model is the preferred concurrency model for **Erlang** and **Rust**.

---

Note that unlike the languages mentioned above most languages don't have cannon or preferred concurrency models and even those languages who show a strong preference for one model usually have the other ones implemented as libraries.

My personal opinion is that Futures outclass STM and Actors in simplicity of use and reasoning but none of these models are inherently "wrong" and I can think of no disadvantages for either. You could use whichever you preferred with no consequences.

Comment: Rust uses CSP and not the actor model, see http://www.lars.com/concurrency/rust/servo/2013/12/21/concurrency-rust-and-servo.html

Answer (score 1):

The most general model for parallel processing is [Petri Nets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Petri_net).  It represents computation as pure data dependency graph, which expreses maximum parallelism. All other models stem from it.

Dataflow Computing model http://www.cs.colostate.edu/cameron/dataflow.html, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dataflow_programming is almost as powerful. It restricts Petri Net places to have only one output arc. In practice, this is useful, as places with multiple output arcs are hard to implement, cause indeterminism, and are rarely needed.

Actor model is a dataflow model where nodes may have only 2 input edges - one for input messages and one for actor's state. This is a serious restriction if you want to program functions with side-effect and  more than one argument.