# What APIs to use for implement CSP / GoRoutines in .NET/F#

Tags: .net, f#, goroutine

I return to .NET after leave for a while in the 2.0 days. Now, I see a lot of APIs/libraries to manage concurrency in .NET.

I like how GoRoutines feel and wish to have something alike in .NET/F#, but I'm unsure about what will be the better foundation for it.

Is important to remember that goroutines work for both IO-bound and CPU-bound scenarios.

P.D: I have full control of the codebase, and last .NET versions for F#/.NET in both windows & mono

Comment: The important thing to know is that while you can intermingle traditional .net libraries written in c#, f# has it's own way of doing things. C# has a language construct 'async/await' which is similar in nature, but different in many ways to F#'s [Asynchronous Workflow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233250.aspx). Whichever way you slice it, they will likely be different in subtle ways from Go. In both cases, these methods will work for both IO-bound and CPU-bound scenarios.

Comment: C#: while `async/await` might work for special CPU-bound scenarios, their typical use is IO. Tasks on the other hand are used for CPU-bound workflows. Asynchronous workflows in F# can be used for both I/O and CPU-heavy applications.

Comment: Ok, In F# I was thinking that agents was the way to go (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35469691/how-implement-csp-on-top-of-agents-in-f). I know the basic of async programming, but not see how async workflows could be used here...

Comment: After thinking for a while, I wonder if this is far simpler. The channel is the key thing (the way how communication happens) so I wonder if just implement a channel type with a concurrentQueue and that is all. Using async or agents or task will not matter much.

Comment: https://github.com/Hopac/Hopac/tree/master/Docs

Comment: @mamcx how did it turn out?